# Where to ask for IT/CS books suggestions?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask for IT/CS books (programming, design, etc...), suggestions both on specific technical topics or rater general theoretical matters; I know Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask as my question(s) would be considered as off-topic for being too wide and subjective, so what I'm asking is: is there a Stack Exchange community where questions about that would be OK? (Software Recommendations maybe?)

Comment: No, it is and remains a very opinionated question that has potential to attract spam. You can ask it and if 10 people answer you'll probably get 8 different answers. Is that ever going to be useful to you and others? I tend to look at Amazon book reviews myself, trying to limit to verified purchases. That has hardly ever steered me wrong so far.

Comment: 1) find related books on amazon 2) sort by rating 3) buy the top two.

Comment: Well maintained tag wikis will have a list of suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The general problem with these kind of recommendations is, as you write, that they're very subjective. Therefore, they are not a good question for *any* Q&A site in this network. Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations only work because they enforce their users to make very detailed requirements. I fear that no site will welcome your question as it currently stands.

See also [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/295232) and a [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) by Jeff Atwoord for this reasons behind this policy.

Comment: This has however not prevented SO from spitting out numerous "book recommendation" lists, all of them very subjective and of low quality. And even though all those book lists are genuine crap, we are apparently not allowed to delete them. Presumably because they generate site traffic.

Comment: Don't forget that SO rewrites Amazon links to include its affiliate code and gets a cut from that.